# How to get Uinversal Analytics sales performance report using Google API (Node js)

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to automate the UA (Universal Analytics) Ecommerce- sales Performance Report using Google API

But i could not find the API for that can any help with this

Need Ecommerce- sales Performance Report  as Array object using google apis

Comment: Google Analytics reporting api will get you that data

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo  can you give me a git hub repo for this. i could not find

Comment: [Google Analytics reporting api ](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)